# SIMD/SSE : short dot product and short max value

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd, intrinsics

I'm trying to optimize a dot product of two c-style arrays of contant and small size and of type short.

I've read several documentations about SIMD intrinsics and many blog posts/articles about dot product optimization using this intrisincs.

However, i don't understand how a dot product on short arrays using this intrinsics can give the right result. When making the dot product, the computed values can be (and are always, in my case) greater than SHORT_MAX, so is there sum. Hence, i store them in a variable of double type.

As i understand the dot product using simd intrinsic, we use __m128i variables types and operations are returning __m128i. So, what i don't understand is why it doesn't "overflow" and how the result can be transformed into a value type that can handle it?

thanks for your advices

Comment: Why do you want to optimize the dot product of two *small* arrays? What else are you doing with these arrays? What are you doing in your critical loop? Some code examples would help.

Comment: I'm trying to optimize the dot product since it takes 80% of the time of the complete process : almost 15 millions different dot products in one run, so that any improvement can have a huge effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the range of your data values you might use an intrinsic such as [_mm_madd_epi16](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yht36sa6(v=vs.100).aspx), which performs multiply/add on 16 bit data and generates 32 bit terms. You would then need to periodically accumulate your 32 bit terms to 64 bits. How often you need to do this depends on the range of your input data, e.g. if it's 12 bit greyscale image data then you can do 64 iterations at 8 elements per iteration (i.e. 512 input points) before there is the potential for overflow. In the worst case however, if your input data uses the full 16 bit range, then you would need to do the additional 64 bit accumulate on every iteration (i.e. every 8 points).

Comment: I haven't seen this function, and now i see the light. I've implemented the dot product and it works, tihout overflow. I have a speed gain of almost 25%, wich is huge for me!

Comment: `_mm_madd_epi16` is somewhere near the top of my top 10 list of SSE intrinsics of all time. ;-) As well as dot products it's also useful for statistics type reductions, e.g. sum(x), sum(x^2), etc. BTW, if you want to post your code as a new question then it should be possible to improve on your 25% gain.

Comment: @florian, I had forgotten about `_mm_madd_epi16`. Thanks to Paul for reminding me about it again. It would be interesting to see your code and more of what you're doing as Paul suggested. Your operation is probably memory bandwidth bound so there is not much you can do except change what your doing but it's hard to say for sure without knowing more about what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, i've also imagined these operations are memory bandwidth bound. Besides, the general process is parallelized, so that i don't expect a 25% gain, but less than that. But, its already a huge improvement (i expected 2 / 5 %). I'll post my code later, but why in another subject?

Comment: and, as another comment, the avx corresponding code is slower.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records, here is how i make an dot product for 2 int16 arrays of size 36:

```
double dotprod(const int16_t* source, const int16_t* target, const int size){
#ifdef USE_SSE
    int res[4];
    __m128i* src = (__m128i *) source;
    __m128i* t = (__m128i *) target;
    __m128i s = _mm_madd_epi16(_mm_loadu_si128(src), mm_loadu_si128(t));
    ++src;
    ++t;
    s = _mm_add_epi32(s, _mm_madd_epi16(_mm_loadu_si128(src), _mm_loadu_si128(t)));
    ++src;
    ++t;
    s = _mm_add_epi32(s, _mm_madd_epi16(_mm_loadu_si128(src), _mm_loadu_si128(t)));
    ++src;
    ++t;
    s = _mm_add_epi32(s, _mm_madd_epi16(_mm_loadu_si128(src), _mm_loadu_si128(t)));

    /* return the sum of the four 32-bit sub sums */
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&res, s);
    return res[0] + res[1] + res[2] + res[3] + source[32] * target[32] + source[33] * target[33] + source[34] * target[34] + source[35] * target[35];
#elif USE_AVX
    int res[8];
    __m256i* src = (__m256i *) source;
    __m256i* t = (__m256i *) target;
    __m256i s = _mm256_madd_epi16(_mm256_loadu_si256(src), _mm256_loadu_si256(t));
    ++src;
    ++t;
    s = _mm256_add_epi32(s, _mm256_madd_epi16(_mm256_loadu_si256(src), _mm256_loadu_si256(t)));

    /* return the sum of the 8 32-bit sub sums */
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&res, s);
    return res[0] + res[1] + res[2] + res[3] + res[4] + res[5] + res[6] + res[7] + source[32] * target[32] + source[33] * target[33] + source[34] * target[34] + source[35] * target[35];
#else
    return source[0] * target[0] + source[1] * target[1] + source[2] * target[2] + source[3] * target[3] + source[4] * target[4]+ source[5] * target[5] + source[6] * target[6] + source[7] * target[7] + source[8] * target[8] + source[9] * target[9] + source[10] * target[10] + source[11] * target[11] + source[12] * target[12] + source[13] * target[13] + source[14] * target[14] + source[15] * target[15] + source[16] * target[16] + source[17] * target[17] + source[18] * target[18] + source[19] * target[19] + source[20] * target[20] + source[21] * target[21] + source[22] * target[22] + source[23] * target[23] + source[24] * target[24] + source[25] * target[25] + source[26] * target[26] + source[27] * target[27] + source[28] * target[28] + source[29] * target[29] + source[30] * target[30] + source[31] * target[31] + source[32] * target[32] + source[33] * target[33] + source[34] * target[34] + source[35] * target[35];
#endif
}
```